# Referring to CSV header string to adjust column format

Tags: python, csv

I'm somewhat new to python and csv processing, but I couldn't find any solutions for what I'm looking for.  When I open up a specific CSV file in excel, I have a column called "rate" that is in percent.  I'm dividing all the values in this column by 100.  As of now I'm referring to this column by calling `row[6] = percentToFloat(row[6])`.  My question is if its possible to address the row by the header name rather than just the column number.

```
with open(input) as inFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    reader.next()
    with open(output, 'w') as outFile:
        writer = csv.writer(outFile)
        for row in reader:
            if len(row)>1:  #skips empty rows
                row[6] = percentToFloat(row[6])
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: See [the docs for `csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and the corresponding `csv.DictWriter()` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) :

```
reader = csv.DictReader(inFile)
```

Now you can use `row['column_name']` instead of `row[6]` in your code.

Comment: I implented csv.DictReader and tried doing `for row in reader: print(row['rate'])` but I get KeyError: 'rate'

Comment: What do you see when you do `print(row.keys())`?

Comment: Now try `print(row)` - this should explain what `row` contains.

Comment: This prints out all 1,000,000 lines

Comment: After printing one, break the loop. That would tell give you one.

Comment: Looks like this: {None: ['member_id', 'loan_amnt', 'funded_amnt', 'funded_amnt_inv', 'term', 'int_rate', 'installment', 'grade', 'sub_grade', '], 'Notes offered by Prospectus (https://www.lendingclub.com/info/prospectus.action)': 'id'}

Comment: There seems to be some issue with your csv file.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I think you might be right

Answer (score 2):

You could use data frames from Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=True)
print(df)

print(df.rate)
print(df.rate/100.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(input) as inFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inFile)
    rate_index = reader.fieldnames.index('rate')
    reader.next()
    with open(output, 'w') as outFile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outFile, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        for row in reader:
            if len(row)>1:  #skips empty rows
                row[rate_index] = percentToFloat(row[6])
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Updated.

Comment: So I have to enter the header names manually like you're doing for `fieldnames`

Comment: Yeah, I'm checking now if there's an automatic way.

Comment: Tell me if it's working, if not, please share the error you encounter.

Comment: At the moment I'm just trying to print(row['rate']) and im getting KeyError: 'rate'

Comment: Is it possible to share your .csv?

Comment: @Brosef Found the error, check the line `writer= csv.DictWriter ...` we need to pass filenames argument. I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but we still have to provide the fieldnames manually...I'm trying to use the column headers that already exist.

Comment: Updated fieldnames, now it should automatically take fieldnames from first row.

Comment: @Brosef Please test the last update and share the result.

Comment: Not sure I understand the last line of your solution.  I have 20-30 fieldnames.  I'm suppose to type them all in?

Comment: I want to write all rows to the new file, not just the rows that are being modified.  Since I have 20+ rows its not very practical to type out every field I want to add in `writer.writerow()`

Comment: @Brosef Maybe you can obtain index for `rate` using `reader.fieldnames` than pass the index like this `row[rate_index]` See updated code.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  My current solution is using the index instead of the column name.

Comment: @Brosef What I propose is, you can get index from fieldnames list, then pass into row[]. Doing this, you won't need to use magical number 6 in row[]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99745/discussion-between-brosef-and-saibot).